# Selecting all text in TextBox when focusing

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, controls

I have a small window with 2 textboxes  in a grid databinded to some properties, it is called from context menu of another window. I made one of textboxes focused after appearing by 
`<Grid  FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=priceBox}">`
I would like to have behavior that Text in TextBox would be selected (dark blue background) so if I start type new symbols old ones being immediately deleted. I don't want to delete old symbols first. Same behavior I would like to have after I press Tab to switch to next textbox.
Is there any textbox settings to achieve this?

I have very old winforms applications and It looks like it was behaving this way by default.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to set Keyboard focus on the TextBox before selecting the text

e.g:

```
private void SelectAllText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }    
}
```